# Removing class elements in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering how I will be able to remove label including input field defined with a class from a validating form. Actually I am retrieving value from database in the form label and I want to remove the form fields which do not have label value. I am trying with the following codes:

**JS**

```
<script>
if ($(label[for="flp"].length < 0)){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("div").remove(".form-group");

    });
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for ="flp" class="col-lg-3 control-label">label</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field1" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I can not understand where I am doing wrong. Will you please help me to figure it out?

Comment: `if ($('label[for="flp"]').length < 0)) {` ???

Comment: I have selected label with for and if characters are less than 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('label').each(function(i,v) {
      if($(v).text().length == 0) {
         $(v).parent('.form-group').remove();
       };
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3c3hp57u/

Comment: I have tried with the code. Will you please give a demo.

Comment: Thank you very much. Second one is working like a charm. This is the code I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `document.ready` at outermost part and keep all your script inside it. Also, your syntax for label length and to remove div with particular class is wrong, see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //if ( $('label[for="flp"]').length < 0)  ){//this will never be true as length will 0 or greater than 0
   if ( $('label[for="flp"]').length == 0)  ){//check length for label element
        $("div.form-group").remove();//remove div with class form-group
   }
});
```

Comment: Does `$('label[for="flp"]').length` return 0 if not existed?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali, yes it will return 0

Comment: @Ramen, actually your condition need to modify little to `if ( $('label[for="flp"]').length == 0)  ){` because `.length` returns 0 or more values and hence `if ( $('label[for="flp"]').length < 0)  ){` will never be true.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar : ^ what i want to mention.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali, thanks for pointing out the problem :). I have updated the same in my answer to help Ramen

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   if (($('label[for="flp"]').text().length)==0){ 
     $("div").remove(".form-group");
   }
});
```

this will work for sure

Comment: have you tried it in jsfidde? If so please show it.

Comment: this code will remove all the div with the mentioned class

Comment: i you need to close only some particular div then you have to mention a specific id for the div

Comment: because classes can be used number of times you know that na